# How to write condition to set free shipping for particular US states in "Shopping Cart Price Rules"?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

I want to enable free shipping if the state is Massachusetts and Order Total Amount is <=250$ or if the state is Connecticut and Order Total Amount is <=500$. How to implement this condition in Shopping cart Price Rules ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set like this using Table rate. Tablerate Content should be like this:

[image]

To set up Table Rates go to System -> Configuration and Select Shipping Methods from the Left Navigation.
Select Your desired website " Current Configuration Scope". I have selected "Main Website".
Make settings like below screenshot:

[image]

Upload your tablerate CSV file in Import field.

Then Save Config.

Refer below link for more clarification:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Comment: Normally a link and one line of text is not the best answer as links can go bad. Maybe you could write a small note on how the csv file should be formatted.

Comment: @David, Thanks for your info. I'll improve my answer.